# How to select a MultipleChoice option based on text variable

Tags: javascript, django, multichoiceitems

I have a MultipleChoiceField and a variable `my_choice = 'mystring'`

I want check the option relative to `my_choice`

Here my `html`:

```
    ul id="id_layer_select"><li><label for="id_layer_select_0"><input checked="checked" id="id_layer_select_0" name="layer_select" type="checkbox" value="1" /> <span style='font-weight:normal'>Mychoice1</span></label></li>
<li><label for="id_layer_select_1"><input id="id_layer_select_1" name="layer_select" type="checkbox" value="2" /> <span style='font-weight:normal'>Mychoice2</span></label></li>
<li><label for="id_layer_select_2"><input id="id_layer_select_2" name="layer_select" type="checkbox" value="3" /> <span style='font-weight:normal'>Mychoice3</span></label></li> [...]</ul>
```

here my `javascript`:

```
var my_choice = 'mystring'
var opt = $("#id_layer_select option");
opt.filter("[value=my_choice]").attr("selected", true);
```

I can use jquery. Thank you

PS: Off course `mystring` is an option `Mychoice1` or `Mychoice2` or etc.

I don't want use the `id_layer_select_x` and I prefer to not add and attribute.

The problem is that the checkbox stay unchecked and

```
console.log(opt)=Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object[1] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter all spans by the text they contain. You can then get the previous element and have it checked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var txt = "Mychoice3";
  
  
  var labelMatchingTxt = $('#id_layer_select span').filter(function(i, el) {
    return txt === el.childNodes[0].nodeValue; // avoiding DOM reselection.
  }).prev().prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>

<body>

<ul id="id_layer_select"><li><label for="id_layer_select_0"><input id="id_layer_select_0" name="layer_select" type="checkbox" value="1" /> <span style='font-weight:normal'>Mychoice1</span></label></li>
<li><label for="id_layer_select_1"><input id="id_layer_select_1" name="layer_select" type="checkbox" value="2" /> <span style='font-weight:normal'>Mychoice2</span></label></li>
<li><label for="id_layer_select_2"><input id="id_layer_select_2" name="layer_select" type="checkbox" value="3" /> <span style='font-weight:normal'>Mychoice3</span></label></li> [...]</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: You are right but doesn't work yet. Console.log(opt)=Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object[1] }. It look wrong to me.